# CSS transition causing briefly causing white space

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

Link to the pen http://codepen.io/mikeCaley/pen/VpYrEq

The transition is working how I want except when you quickly move your mouse across from one side to the other you will see that white space appears on the right.

I can't understand why this is because the transition speed for all the divs is the same.

The only fix I have come up with is to match the background colour, however I need a more robust solution (and would also like to know why this is happening)

```
<div class="slider-wrap">
  <div class="placeholder p1"></div>
  <div class="placeholder p2"></div>
  <div class="placeholder p3"></div>
</div>

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size:0;
  outline: solid black 0.1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.placeholder {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.3333%;
  background-color: black;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 41% 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: width 0.4s linear;
}

.p1 {
  background-image: url(https://riverisland.scene7.com/is/image/RiverIsland/C20170224_P1_Spring_970x500_2_DNT?$retina$);
  left:0;
}

.p2 {
  background-image: url(https://riverisland.scene7.com/is/image/RiverIsland/C20170224_P1_Spring_970x500_1_DNT?$retina$);
}

.p3 {
  background-image: url(https://riverisland.scene7.com/is/image/RiverIsland/C20170224_P1_Spring_970x500_3_DNT?$retina$);
}

.slider-wrap:hover .p1,
.slider-wrap:hover .p2,
.slider-wrap:hover .p3 {
  width:30%;
}

.slider-wrap .p1:hover {
  width: 40%;
}
.slider-wrap .p2:hover {
  width: 40%;
}
.slider-wrap .p3:hover {
  width: 40%;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Your codepen has different code than your question. This is in the codepen, but not the question: .slider-wrap:hover .p1,
.slider-wrap:hover .p2,
.slider-wrap:hover .p3 {
  width:30%;
}

Comment: There seems to be another problem. How come when you hover over the right border a large white space appears. This happens without hovering over the other sections.

Comment: Must have copied it wrong.
I've changed the border to an outline so that doesn't happen anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why white space is appearing on the right hand side of the accordion is because of the transition and the following code.

```
.slider-wrap:hover .p1,
.slider-wrap:hover .p2,
.slider-wrap:hover .p3 {
  width:30%;
}
```

Because the transition is .4s long, the user can hover over each slider-wrap p# and trigger its transition to `width:30%` in less than .4s. This will cause each slider-wrap's width transition to overlap and their total width to be between 90% and 100%.

To solve the problem you need to ensure that the sum of the p#'s widths is never less than 100%.

One solution is to use flexbox. By setting `.slider-wrap` to `display: flex` and setting each child's `flex-grow: 1`, any extra space within `.slider-wrap` will be filled.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider-wrap {
  display:flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size:0;
  outline: solid black 0.1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.placeholder {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.3333%;
  background-color: black;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 41% 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: width 0.4s linear;
  flex-grow:1;
}

.p1 {
  background-image: url(https://riverisland.scene7.com/is/image/RiverIsland/C20170224_P1_Spring_970x500_2_DNT?$retina$);
  left:0;
}

.p2 {
  background-image: url(https://riverisland.scene7.com/is/image/RiverIsland/C20170224_P1_Spring_970x500_1_DNT?$retina$);
}

.p3 {
  background-image: url(https://riverisland.scene7.com/is/image/RiverIsland/C20170224_P1_Spring_970x500_3_DNT?$retina$);
}

.slider-wrap:hover .p1,
.slider-wrap:hover .p2,
.slider-wrap:hover .p3 {
  width:30%;
}

.slider-wrap .p1:hover {
  width: 40%;
}
.slider-wrap .p2:hover {
  width: 40%;
}
.slider-wrap .p3:hover {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-wrap">
  <div class="placeholder p1"></div>
  <div class="placeholder p2"></div>
  <div class="placeholder p3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Let me know if this works for you or if there is any reason you don't want to use flexbox?

Comment: That's beautiful, thanks. Just hadn't thought to use it, flex box wasn't really around when I learnt CSS. Need to brush up on it

Comment: Glad to help out. Flexbox is really powerful and fun to work with. CSS Tricks has a great article if you want to learn more. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/